# What type of wire to use in underwater applications

Tags: electrical, well-pump, well

I live in the San Diego County (CA) and I am trying to resurrect a well and I have a question about the type of wire that I need to use from the control box down the shaft of the well.  From the research I've done to date, I need to use submersible wire, but I am seeing conflicting information that UL direct burial would work as a substitute.

The question is, to be up to code, what type of wire do I need to run down the well to the pump?

Comment: There is special wire made specifically for going down well shafts.  It is not only wet rated, but is also health-rated for being in contact with potable water.  You would not want to lick THWN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use submersible pump cable -- it's what's listed and tested for the job

Submersible pump cable uses a different jacket and insulation composition than other wet-location cables, as it must meet standards for potable water use (NSF/ANSI 61, to be precise) as well as the applicable electrical standards.  The downside is that it must be run in conduit if it exits the wellbore, as it does not have quite the mechanical durability of a direct bury cable.

Comment: This is the only correct way to connect up a submersible pump.+